# Vim: execute the script I'm working on in a split screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, python

I'm working on a small python script, which needs frequent execution in order to debug and further develop.

Can I split the vim screen and execute my script on one part with a keystroke?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line to your .vimrc:

```
command R !./%
```

And then you can just type ":R" while in Vim to run the script ([vim-run-current-file](http://www.calebmadrigal.com/vim-run-current-file/))

Answer (score 10):

Vim does not, and will never support an embedded shell like emacs or kate (if you mean that), see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236563/how-to-run-a-terminal-inside-of-vim).

David Spillet is right, you can run your vim inside gnu screen:

```
$ screen vim foo.txt
```

But that will only give you something remotely resembling a windowmanager in a terminal - VERY useful when used over ssh or on a box with no X, but locally you can just as well open another xterm and switch between them.*

Anyway, if you can live with the fact that you won't see the file you're editing while looking at the output it produces, Jack M's tip is good, but could be shorter:

```
:map ;e :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

For the same purpose, I have this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
au BufEnter *
\if match( getline(1) , '^\#!') == 0 |
\ execute("let b:interpreter = getline(1)[2:]") |
\endif

fun! CallInterpreter()
    if exists("b:interpreter")
         exec ("!".b:interpreter." %")
    endif
endfun

map <F5> :call CallInterpreter()<CR>
```

This runs any file that has a shebang (`#!`) on the first line. It uses the interpreter to run the file, so it does not need to have execute permissions.

*(screen has some other very neat features like copy-and paste from the output, monitoring hidden windows for activity/no-activity, being able to use the session from different terminals at the same time, being able to log out leaving all programs running - it is a powerful tool).

Comment: This autocommand didn't work for me until I put the first line (with the \if) on the same line as the au BufEnter but I removed the \

Comment: Vim might not support a shell natively, but I just wanted to mention this interesting shell plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771

Comment: `:map ;e :w<cr>:!python %<cr>` wants to echo stuff to my vim buffer to "confirm" (?) that the command ran. How do I get it to simply execute the command silently? `:map <silent> ...` does not appear to work.

Answer (score 5):

The least verbose way (which requires your script to be executable) is probably:

```
 :!%
```

Comment: For this to work, I had to modify it to `:!./%` so that the script would be found in the current directory.

Comment: And, I'm not an expert, but it appears that the `!` tells vim to execute whatever follows as a bash command, so you can do `!echo "Hello"`. The `%` is expanded to be the name of the current file.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be split-screen, but this works rather well for me:

```
map ;e :w<CR>:exe ":!python " . getreg("%") . "" <CR>
```

This maps `;e` to write out the current file, and execute it using python (it assumes that python is on your `PATH`).

Answer (score 2):

The [Bexec](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1788) vim plugin does exactly what you want. Keyboard shortcuts included.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953398/how-to-execute-file-im-editing-in-vim/953425#953425).

Answer (score 0):

```
map <F5> :w<CR>:exe ":!python " . getreg("%") . "" <CR>
```

Is what I used with please (F5 runs the current script).

For turning vim into a powerful python IDE i recommend this tutorial:

- http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide

Answer (score 0):

Put [this small snippet](https://github.com/emorikawa/dotfiles/blob/44b25821891a6873dab10364728bc7df99450b7c/vim/vimrc#L496-L542) in your .vimrc to execute the current file with one keystroke (like `F5`) and display the result in a new split-pane buffer.

`:!` is okay but you need to switch to your terminal to see the result.

While you can do that with `ctrl-z` and bring vim back with `fg` it still means you need to switch context a lot.

The way this [snippet](https://github.com/emorikawa/dotfiles/blob/44b25821891a6873dab10364728bc7df99450b7c/vim/vimrc#L496-L542) works is by first guessing the executable based on the `filetype` and then running it with the current file as its argument.

Next a [handy utility method](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window) takes the output and dumps it into a new buffer.

It's not perfect, but really fast for common workflows.

Here's the snippet copied below:

```
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"""""""""""""""""""""""""" RUN CURRENT FILE """""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Execute current file
nnoremap <F5> :call ExecuteFile()<CR>

" Will attempt to execute the current file based on the `&filetype`
" You need to manually map the filetypes you use most commonly to the
" correct shell command.
function! ExecuteFile()
  let filetype_to_command = {
  \   'javascript': 'node',
  \   'coffee': 'coffee',
  \   'python': 'python',
  \   'html': 'open',
  \   'sh': 'sh'
  \ }
  let cmd = get(filetype_to_command, &filetype, &filetype)
  call RunShellCommand(cmd." %s")
endfunction

" Enter any shell command and have the output appear in a new buffer
" For example, to word count the current file:
"
"   :Shell wc %s
"
" Thanks to: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
function! RunShellCommand(cmdline)
  echo a:cmdline
  let expanded_cmdline = a:cmdline
  for part in split(a:cmdline, ' ')
     if part[0] =~ '\v[%#<]'
        let expanded_part = fnameescape(expand(part))
        let expanded_cmdline = substitute(expanded_cmdline, part, expanded_part, '')
     endif
  endfor
  botright new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
  call setline(1, 'You entered:    ' . a:cmdline)
  call setline(2, 'Expanded Form:  ' .expanded_cmdline)
  call setline(3,substitute(getline(2),'.','=','g'))
  execute '$read !'. expanded_cmdline
  setlocal nomodifiable
  1
endfunction
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about vim directly, but you can split the screen in this way generally with the `screen` utility. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> (note, that is a capital S) will split the display and you can switch between the two with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd> (if the window is empty, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>n</kbd> to move to another open window or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd> to create a new one).

You can split the display into more then two too, and change the size of the splits with ctrl-a,:resize . I use screen this way often, and while it isn't the single-key solution you ask for it can be very convenient.

Comment: Are you sure it's working for Vim? It does not seem to respond in my vim (I use the slpit command to split between files).

Comment: These are GNU screen, not vim, commands.

Comment: Yep. I'm talking about running vim within screen.

Comment: a vim split is something that happens within the realm of the vim window (or the terminal that it's running in).