# Can I open a split build window in gvim 8.1 that shows the build output live while I can continue looking at code?

Tags: vim, gvim, vim-plugins

I like using gvim but I think its kind of time consuming to have to always watch the build process complete until I can continue editing.
I'd like to just hit a key and have a bottom split open up where I can see the code being compiled as well as the errors once its done, that automaticly scrolls to the bottom of the output.
I know theres vim dispatch, which does pretty much exactly what I want, but it seams to only work with vim and tmux and not with gvim.
Now is there anyway to emulate the same behaviour with gvim?
So I can just see the build ouput without interrupting my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version is your gvim? The latest
[Vim/gVim 8.1](https://www.vim.org/vim-8.1-released.php)
supports split windows:

[image]

Otherwise, you could use a workaround like this:

```
:!gvim -c 'MyMake'
```

You could also see whether [dispatch.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch#readme)
is helpful ([video Trailer](http://vimeo.com/63116209)):

> Leverage the power of Vim's compiler plugins without being bound by synchronicity. Kick off builds and test suites using one of several asynchronous adapters (including tmux, screen, iTerm, Windows, and a headless mode), and when the job completes, errors will be loaded and parsed automatically.

Comment: I use gvim 8.1 as it says in the title. And didnt vim always support splits? Also vim dispatch does nt seam to work with gvim.

Comment: Do you mean that your gvim doesn't support splits?

Comment: Yes it does, but vim-dispach doesn't work with those for some reason. But you meantioned that vsplits are a vim 8.1 exclusive feature

Comment: I meant if your version doesn't support them then you should upgrade.

Comment: It supports splits, every vim version since 2006 supports splits

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: Well they don't allow ansynchronously exectuing a make command and seeing the output while editing at the same time

Comment: The image in my answer seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: How did you run a command inside a split? Using :ter?

Comment: See [post1](https://superuser.com/questions/868920/open-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-a-split-pane), [post2](https://superuser.com/questions/20625/vim-execute-the-script-im-working-on-in-a-split-screen), and perhaps the Plugin [AsyncRun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim).